# Is the hyperplane with maximal distance to two convex hulls identical with the hyperplane with maximal distance to the two point sets of the hulls?

Tags: geometry

Let's say we're given two sets of points, $(x_i)_{i\in k_1},(y_i)_{i\in k_2}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ which can be linearly separated by a hyperplane of dimension $n-1$.

We're now looking for a hyperplane $H$ that separates the both point sets $(x_i)_{i\in k_1},(y_i)_{i\in k_2}$, while maximizing the distance of the hyperplane to its closest point to it.

(This is exactly the methodic behind Support Vector Machines)

Let $H^\bot$ be a specific orthogonal vector of $H$ and $d(H,x)= \min_{y\in H} d(y,x)$, i.e. the  distance between the hyperplane $H$ and the point $x$. Then we can describe the problem as an optimization problem as follows:
$$
\max_H{\min{\{}}d\left(H,x\right)\mid x\in\{x_1,..,x_{k_1},y_1,..,y_{k_2}\}\} 
$$
under the constraints
$$   H^\bot x_i>0  , i=1,\ldots,k_1\\
   H^\bot y_i<0  , i=1,\ldots,k_2
$$

We could now ask the same question for the convex hulls of our two sets of points:

$$
\max_H{\min{\{}}d\left(H,x\right)\mid x\in conv(\{x_1,..,x_{k_1}\})\cup conv(\{y_1,..,y_{k_2}\})\} 
$$

My question now is: Are the resulting hyperplanes you'd get from each problem both equally good? Are they equal? Are the results dependent on what norm $d$ we use?

Comment: You need to specify that $H$ is limited to hyperplanes separating the two sets. Otherwise there is no maximum distance.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's a critical part I missed there. I've added the part and the constraints!

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, The closest points in the convex hulls to any non-intersecting hyperplane will be support points. Any smooth function on a convex set will have its extrema where all the partial derivatives are $0$, or on the boundary. The derivatives of the distance function to the hyperplane are never all $0$, so the extrema are on the boundary, But the boundary is itself composed of convex facets, so the extrema is along the boundary of the facets. And the same is true of those boundaries. This continues down to the vertices, which are all support points.